# Laravel blade showing curly brackets and controls

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My output is showing curly brackets and the Laravel controls as in the example below and the values are not being printed.

```
...
{{ $tb['ics'] }}
@if ($tb['scope'])
...
@endif @if(count($tb['icstostd']) > 0 )
@foreach ($tb['icstostd'] as $li) @endforeach
WIN Reference   Title       Status
{{ $li['win'] }}    {{ $li['ref'] }}    {{ $li['ref'] }}    {{ $li['title'] }}  {{ $li['title2'] }} {{ $li['status'] }}
@endif
```

I've used this code in other parts of the application and it worked fine but now the variables will only print if I use `"<?= $variable ?>"`.

Here is the controller code.

```
return View::make('books.ics')->with('title',"Body Viewer")
                                ->with('messages',$messages)
                                ->with('searchResults',null)
                                ->with('tb',$tb_array)
                                ->with('tb_name',null);
```

Here is ics.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('header')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/books/wi.css" /> 
@stop

@section('content')

@if (is_array($tb))
    @include('books.partials.icsDisplay',array('tb'=>$tb))
@endif

@stop
```

Here is the sample code for icsDisplay.php

```
<div id="icsDisplay" class="displayBox">

    <div>
        <div class="displayItem long">
            <span class="label"> Title:</span>
            <span class="value"> <?= $tb['title']?> </span>
        </div>
        <div class="displayItem long">
            <span class="label">ICS Code:</span>
            <span class="value">{{ $tb['ics'] }}</span>
        </div>      
        @if ($tb['scope'])
        <div class="displayItem long">
            <span class="label">Scope:</span>
            <span class="value"><?= $tb['scope'] ?></span>
        </div>      
        @endif

        @if(count($tb['icstostd']) > 0 )
        <div class="eventBox longBox">
            <h2>Books</h2>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>WIN</th>
            <th>Reference</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <?php $evens = null ?>
            @foreach ($tb['icstostd'] as $li)
            <tr{{ $evens }}>
                <td>{{ $li['win'] }} </td>
                <td class="actionCol"><a href='/omailly/books/{{ $li['win'] }}'>{{ $li['ref'] }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $li['ref'] }} </td>
                <td>{{ $li['title'] }} </td>
                <td>{{ $li['title2'] }} </td>
                <td>{{ $li['status'] }} </td>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($evens) {$evens = null;} else {$evens = " class='even'";} ?>
            @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
        @endif

    </div>

</div>
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post complete `books.ics` view code? You can edit your question and add it.

Comment: Is it only this file? Does it still work on other pages?

Comment: Just to confirm: your blade file is saved as `ics.blade.php`, right?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I've made an edit and included the ics.blade.php code

Comment: @aynber I've reused this code in other pages and seems to work fine.

Comment: @camelCase Yes, the file is saved as ics.blade.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always add .blade.php to the files you are using the Blade engine with.

Try to rename your icsDisplay.php into icsDisplay.blade.php.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That did the trick.  I renamed icsDisplay.php to icsDisplay.blade.php.  I wonder how the other pages worked without me using blade in the name.